# Generate random pairs of items within a vector

Tags: r, random

Suppose I have a character vector (e.g. `myv = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')`), I would like to randomly generate `n = length(myv)` pairs of `partner1 - partner2` coming from this vector, knowing that:

- all items should be 1 time `partner1` and 1 time `partner2`, not more and not less, in random order;
- an item cannot be partner with itself (save value for `partner1` and `partner2` does not work).

I am not finding an elegant way to do this (e.g. with `sample`, `combn` or `expand.grid`), so I currently use an ugly `for` loop:

```
set.seed(11)

myv = letters[1:5]

irand = sample(length(myv), length(myv)) # to randomly select partner1

allpairs = expand.grid(myv, myv)
# remove pairs of the same item
allpairs = allpairs[allpairs[,1]!=allpairs[,2],]

usedpartner2 = c() # to store the partner2 which are already used
mypairs = c() # to store results
for (i in 1:length(myv)) {
  partner1 = myv[irand[i]]
  # the potential partner2 must be different from partner1 and not already used
  candidates = allpairs[allpairs[, 1]==partner1 & !(allpairs[, 2] %in% usedpartner2), 2]
  partner2 = as.character(candidates[sample(length(candidates), 1)])
  usedpartner2 = c(usedpartner2, partner2)
  mypairs = rbind(mypairs, c(partner1, partner2))
}

mypairs
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "b"  "e" 
# [2,] "a"  "b" 
# [3,] "e"  "a" 
# [4,] "d"  "c" 
# [5,] "c"  "d"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could see `myv` as a ring and turn it randomly by adding something in molulo (`%%`) of `length(myv)` (zero excluded). `(length(myv) - 1) %% length(myv)` should be excluded to avoid elements getting paired with itself. This should work with arbitrary lengths of `myv` and seeds respectively.

```
matrix(c(myv, 
         myv[(seq_along(myv) + sample(seq_along(myv)[- (length(myv) - 1)], 1)) 
             %% length(myv) + 1]), 
       ncol=2)
```

You then could easily wrap this into a function.

```
pairOff <- function(x) {
  x <- sample(x)  # to get first column into random order, too
  M <- matrix(c(x, 
                x[(seq_along(x) + sample(seq_along(x)[- (length(x) - 1)], 1)) 
                  %% length(x) + 1]), 
              ncol=2)
  return(M)
}
```

***Yielding***

```
> pairOff(myv)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "d"  "e" 
[2,] "c"  "a" 
[3,] "b"  "d" 
[4,] "e"  "c" 
[5,] "a"  "b"
```

***Data***

```
set.seed(165472)
myv <- letters[1:5]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works indeed - 1 minor detail (I edited my question for clarity): they needed to be in random order, also `partner1`. In your solution, I guess it would just mean to reorganize the rows of your result matrix randomly afterwards.

Comment: Probably better is to rather randomize the input than the resulting matrix, because it's slightly faster. I've edited the code accordingly.